# How to set current date for <input type="date" id="availableDate" value =" "/>

Tags: javascript

I'm new in JavaScript. Here is JavaScript page file source code :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="New.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="corona.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }

      #container {
        min-height: 100%;
      }  
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      Date: <input type="date" id="availableDate" value="2020-01-29" />
      <input type="button" value="Run" id="button1">
      <br>
    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    <strong>Ajax Response</strong>:
    <div id="ajaxGetUserServletResponse"></div>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I edited this code to get current date when I open that page. Thank you

Comment: Hope this fiddle will help you into it. http://jsfiddle.net/7LXPq/93/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("availableDate").valueAsDate = new Date();
```